# Perl case-insensitive regex not working

Tags: regex, perl

Here is the entire script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.14; use warnings;

my $reg = qr/test/i;

say "matched 1" if $reg =~ "test"; # matches
say "matched 2" if $reg =~ "Test"; # no match
```

The first case matches, the second doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The binding operator `=~` has the *string* on the *left*, and the *regular expression* on the *right*.

```
"test" =~ $reg;
```

Comment: That is bizarre. Why would case 1 work but not case 2 if they're in the wrong order? Anyway thank you.

Comment: Because case 1 is interpreted as `'(?^ui:test)' =~ /test/`, while the second as `'(?^ui:test)' =~ /Test/`. Search for "stringification" in [perlre](http://p3rl.org/perlre).

Answer (score 2):

> That is bizarre. Why would that matter?

The order of parameters is significant in most operators; commutative operators are a rarity.

- `2 / 3` is different from `3 / 2`
- `2 - 3` is different from `3 - 2`
- `2 > 3` is different from `3 > 2`
- `2 << 3` is different from `3 << 2`
- `$x = 2` is different from `2 = $x`

I could obviously go on. The same thing applies to `!=`, `!~`, `%`, `&&`, `*`, `**`, `*=`, `+`, `+=`, `,`, `-`, `-=`, `->`, `.`, `..`, `...`, `/`, `//`, `<`, `<<`, `<=`, `=`, `=>`, `=~`, `>`, `>=`, `>>`, `^`, `and`, `ge`, `gt`, `le`, `lt`, `or`, `x`, `||` and `~~`. And that is without mentioning the named operators with more than one parameter that also behave as functions, such as `split`, `splice`, `join`, `open` etc. All things considered, I am *astonished* that you find it bizarre that `=~` is non-commutative

> And why would case 1 work but not case 2 if they're in the wrong order?

Because in `$reg =~ "test"`, Perl coerces `$reg` to a string, giving `(?^ui:test)`, and the string to a regex, giving `qr/test/`. So it does

```
say "matched 1" if "(?^ui:test)" =~ /test/;
```

which is successful because `(?^ui:test)` does contain `test`. However it *doesn't* contain `Test` so

```
say "matched 1" if "(?^ui:test)" =~ /Test/
```

prints nothing

Comment: The order of parameters matters for `==` and `eq`? Because that was my misunderstanding. I was looking at `=~` like an equality operator when (I now see that) it isn't.